# Adjectives to describe dismissive or disrespectful behaviour?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What adjectives describe the behaviour of someone who is dismissive of, or disrespectful towards, another's capabilities, knowledge, experience, or professional responsibilities?

The specific context is a manager who sometimes disregards the competency of his supervisees, or is dismissive of a supervisee's responsibilities. Examples of such behaviours include: refusing to listen to the concerns of his supervisee and instead trivialising them, only to later listen attentively and provide suggestions during a team meeting; delegating the responsibility of formulating and managing a staff roster to a team supervisor, only to then (seemingly on a whim) direct a staff member to take time-off without consulting or advising the junior supervisor; allocating tasks that are arguably the remit of the team supervisor to a junior team member without any discussion with the team supervisor.

I am not sure *dismissive* or *disregard* are the most suitable adjectives. *Arrogant* and *disdainful* may be applicable, but these have strong connotations and their usage, when describing such unacceptable behaviour to the manager, might be perceived as confrontational.

An example sentence in which I'd like to use such an adjective is:
"It is [insert adjective] to expect the team supervisor to formulate the roster, manage staff, and develop work plans, only to then undermine these by changing staff availability without consultation."

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing in the preamble is fundamentally confrontational. Words like *dismissive* and *arrogant* seem to fit the bill.

With respect to the example sentence, consider *unreasonable*, *inefficient*, *pernicious*, and *counterproductive* (my favourite).

Comment: Thanks Dan. I edited the OP to clarify what I intended to convey with respect to using arrogant and disdainful as descriptors of behaviour as confrontational.